# How does playbackRate affect bandwidth consumption with videojs?

Tags: video.js

I'm using videojs to playback videos stored on AWS. My users will often play back the video at 4x, 8x, or 16x speed. I can control the playback speed using:

```
videojs('my-player', {playbackRates: [1, 4, 8, 16]})
```

How does this impact bandwidth usage? Does a video played at 4x speed consume 1/4 of the bandwidth?

Are there other web video frameworks that would be better suited to minimizing data transfer out when playback speed is increased?

Answer (score 0):

Most (if not all) HTML5 video player libraries are just wrappers for native HTML5. So buffering etc is handled by browser according to standardized RFC protocols. On the other hand, HLS/DASH features requires custom implementation by player.

Comment: OK, how do browsers implementing HTML5 video handle playback speed > 1x? How does this affect bandwidth consumption?

Comment: @chris_mac I dont think, it affects bandwith. Video can be fully buffered based on connection speed and file size once you play the video. You can run out of buffered segment (loading spinner) even on rate 1x if there is poor connection. As far as I know there is no throttling based on playbackRate.